# how to create cgpa of student

Tags: database, oracle

```
i am trying to create the cgpa for students from my result table.
i have the result table where i have the points and grade of each course of a student in a semister.
```

now i am trying to calculate the gpa from the points of each semister and finally calculating the cgpa of the student
    i have the following table:

```
create table result(
id number(2),
roll number(10),
c_id varchar(30),
marks number (6,2),
year number(3),
term number(3),
credit integer CHECK(credit>0 and credit<5),
points number(3,2),
grade varchar (4)
);

ALTER TABLE result ADD FOREIGN KEY (roll) REFERENCES student(roll)
ALTER TABLE result ADD FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES courses(c_id)

i have inserted the result of two terms of a student.

insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (1,1307001,'cse 3103',200,2,1,3,4,'A+');
insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (2,1307001,'cse 3105',200,2,1,3,3.5,'A');
insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (3,1307001,'cse 3109',200,2,1,4,3.25,'B+');

insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (1,1307001,'cse 3103',200,3,1,4,3.5,'A');
insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (2,1307001,'cse 3103',200,3,1,3,3.25,'B+');
insert into result (id,roll,c_id,marks,year,term,credit,points,grade) values (3,1307001,'cse 3103',200,3,1,3,3.00,'B');



now how can i calculate the gpa of each term of student.and then the cgpa..help please

thanks in advance..

gpa formula:
gpa=summation of ((credit*points) of each course) divided by total credit in a semister;
```

Comment: Does semister is combination if year and term in your table?

Comment: yes. 2nd year 1st term is a semister..

Comment: Provide expected result for your test data. For me it is still dififcult to understand what your want from your desrciption

Comment: i want to get the gpa ot 2nd year 1st term and the gpa of 3rd year 1st term seperately . will it work :  SELECT roll, c_id , (SUM(credit*Points))/(SUM(credit))
FROM result
Group BY roll, c_id.

Comment: getting error:   total:=total+point;
*
ERROR at line 26:
ORA-06550: line 25, column 2:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 22, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: my code link:http://paste.ubuntu.com/21635775/